# Default DatePicker & TimePicker label not localize

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, localization, datetimepicker

I'm using a `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`. The functionality works fine, but when I change the language to Japanese only "OK" label is not translated. It works fine in other language like Spanish.

So is there any way?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom or an android-generated resource? MAke sure it is translated if it is your own. OK may not be translated using the strings make by Android(android.R....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a native Japanese speaker and I believe "OK" is correctly translated. I say "OK" is translated as "OK" into Japanese.

Most Japanese people understand what "OK" means and it's very usual for Japanese people to see label saying "OK" on their phone.

Screen shot below is iOS Facebook messenger app asking for camera access on my iPhone (language is set to Japanese). You see label saying "OK". If a Japanese tap "OK", camera access will be allowed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification.